# Eroot World’s Strongest Root Tool: Scam or No Scam - That Is The Question?

Tags: rooting

**"Eroot (phone one key root tools) is a free android root tool which is developed by China root team. It is a new tool and become the World’s Strongest Root Tool. Currently the Eroot supports Samsung, Motorola, Huawei, SONY, HTC’s most models, the total number of models have more than 200 models. Root success rate in the industry leader."**

Source: [Android Groupon](http://www.androidgroupon.com/2013/05/29/eroot-worlds-strongest-root-tool.html)

Things that are too good to be true usually are !!

However is this a tool to stay away from or a legitimate product that every android enthusiast should keep by their side ?

Anyone with experience of the above & can comment on its effectiveness, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Is there an English version? This is very vague, risking to root without knowing what you are clicking.

Comment: @AnasAzeem The link is no longer active, I'll trying looking for another one when I have some time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it works.I rooted sony er wt19i with locked bootloader and it installed superuser.You should try.Many people asking can  I do this or that  and never did nothing. How can you know if you didnt try?